# Unable to render two components from App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to javascript and React. I am trying to render two components Layout and Home from App.js. When I tried rendering Layout component alone from App.js. Its working. But When I added Home component in App.js. Both are not working. Can anyone please help me out to resolve the issue. Below is my code

App.js

```
import './App.scss';
import { Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import React from 'react';
import Layout from './Components/Layout';
import Home from './Components/Home';

function App()
{
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />} />
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
         
      </Routes>
    </>
    )
}



export default App
```

Home.js

```
import LogoTitle from  '../../assets/images/logo-s.png'

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div className="container home-page">
            <div className="text-zone">
                <hl>Hello World </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


export default Home
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some thing like. (index Route keep it nested)

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its not working!

Answer (score 0):

You need to carefully read the react-router-dom documentation. According to the documentation,

1. You must import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom".
2. You must wrap everything you return inside  element.
3. You need to give every component a path to get that element on any action you're intended to get on.

> ```
> import './App.scss';
> import React from "react";
> import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
> import Layout from './Components/Layout';
> import Home from './Components/Home';
>
> export default function App() {
>   return (
>     <Router>    
>         <div>
>             <Routes>
>                  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />} />
>                  <Route path="/Home" element={<Home />} />
>             </Routes>
>       </div>
>     </Router>
>   );
> }
>
>
> export default App
> ```

4. If you want to get a specific component on some action e.g. on click, like inside home component, you first need to import { link } from "react-router-dom" and then use this as used in the code given below:

> ```
> import LogoTitle from  '../../assets/images/logo-s.png'
> import { link } from "react-router-dom"
>
> const Home = () => {
>     return (
>         <Link to="/">Home</Link> //This must be inside your layout element, 
>                                  //because this is your homepage for your 
>                                  //website, according to how you have defined 
>                                  //your routes.
>     );
> }
>
>
> export default Home
> ```

Comment: with respect to 3 rd point "<Route index element={<Home />} />" I gave like this and tried the same with what u gave, still not working

Comment: Have you given a path to it? There's no path in your commented line of code.

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

try and run please this code block

```
function App()
{
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
      <Route path="/layout " element={<Layout />} />
      <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have tried this still not working